# Same CNAME for various email sending DNSes

Tags: email, cname, multi-subdomains

There are several CNAME related questions on this SE community, but this is a bit different: we'd like the *same* subdomain to send email to our users. But the systems that send these emails include Mailchimp, MS Dynamics, Okta, and so on. All very common corporate systems.

All of these systems need a subdomain, a CNAME, to map to their name server IPs.

Question: if we want our FROM email address to be from the same subdomain, can we map the same CNAME (e.g., `interactive.example.com`) to multiple IPs from various providers?

Comment: It isn't very common practice to use a subdomain in email addresses.  Most of the time you would send all the emails from addresses `@example.com` witthout any subdomain.

Comment: I expect you misunderstand what is going on here.   The CNAMES are likely used with their respective DKIM records to help with mail delivery by adding a  public key associated with their selector so they can sign emails - this has nothing to do with IP addresses.  You can have multiple selectors with different public keys, so multiple providers can each have their own selectors for signing - and you can add selectors and keys for yourself - but really, from the way you asked the question you probably need to get an expert to help you set this all up.

Comment: You can not have multiple CNAMES for for the same subdomain going to multiple  IPs for multiple providers, except possibly in a very obscure niche load-balancing solution.

Comment: @davidgo thanks for the first comment. I'd like to keep the same subdomain if possible, and have multiple software platforms (as listed) add the DKIM, DMARC, SPF etc with it that singular subdomain or domain. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use multiple software platforms and have multiple record types for a subdomain, but **you can't have a CNAME and other normal record types for the same subdomain** - you will need to use A records (or ALIAS constructs if your DNS provider supports them) in place of CNAME records.    (This is clarified/stipulated in section 10.1 of RFC2181 - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181 which reads "An alias name (label of a CNAME record) may,  if DNSSEC is in use, have SIG, NXT, and KEY RRs, but **may have no other data.** " )